# Mongoose populating an array of number without objectid

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to populate an array of Numbers with mongoose. The problem is that these numbers are not objectIds so I tried to user Virtual but with no luck.

This is where I am right now:

Schema 1:

```
const chronic_disease = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    en : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }  
    
});
```

Schema2:

```
const {allergy, behavior, cat_blood_type, cat_breed, chronic_disease, disability,
dog_blood_type, dog_breed, gender, pet_color , sterilized, species } = require('./petsettings');
const ChronicDiseaseModel = mongoose.model('ChronicDisease', chronic_disease, 'chronic_deseases');  

const petSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
    ...
    chronicArray:{type: [Number]},
    ....
});

petSchema.virtual('chronics', {
   ref: 'ChronicDisease',
   localField: 'chronicArray',
   foreignField: 'id',
   select: 'title en'
});
```

I populate the chronics array inside the schema like this:

```
petSchema.methods.populateForLang = async function(lang) {
...
    return await this.populate(['petGender','type', 'allergiesArray', 'chronics' ]);
}
```

but in the output I don't see th 'chronics' field nor the chronicsArray populated.

Any help is appreciated.